# Is there a programming language that allows assigning multiple types to a single variable

Tags: function, types, parameter-passing

Let's assume we have the following code:

```
UpVec sumUpVectors(UpVec vecX, UpVec vecY) { ... return vecResult; }
LeftVec sumLeftVectors(LeftVec vecX, LeftVec vecY) { ... return vecResult; }
```

Is there a programming language that allows, in a moderately straightforward fashion, code such as this:

```
UpVec Up;
LeftVec Left;
UpVec, LeftVec mixedVec;

sumUpVectors (Up, Up);
sumUpVectors(mixedVec, Up); // no type errors
sumLeftVectors(mixedVec, Left); // no type errors
sumLeftVectors(Up, Left); // type error
```

In the above pseudocode, the variable `Up` is of the type `UpVec`, the variable `Left` is of the type `LeftVec`, and the variable `mixedVec` is of both `UpVec` and `LeftVec`. The variable `mixedVec` can be passed both into the function requiring only `UpVec` variables and into the function requiring `LeftVec` variables without a type error, whereas the variables `Up` and `Left` cannot.

The hypothetical language wouldn't force the user to explicitly create a new type as a combination/union of two pre-existing types and then assign the new single type to a variable. This is also avoiding the use of overloading functions either manually or at compile time: there should only be one function `sumUpVectors` and one `sumLeftVectors`.

I presume this would be done using some sort of under-the-hood multiple inheritance of whole classes, but I do not see a straightforward way of doing this without involving extensive overloading.

Comment: probably JavaScript and Kotlin are such languages

Comment: @gpl as far as I understand Kotlin, it doesn't allow this and instead engages in overloading a function